# Javascript - Explicit decimal values separated by comma

Tags: javascript, decimal

I have a JavaScript and HTML form to make a different sums and multiplications. In general, the script works fine, but in some cases, it does not apply the decimal separator and does not display decimal values.

This is the JavaScript when it sums the values well calculated in the precedent script with decimal separator (example: `228.8`). This script returns the value of the sum `1040+228.8-208 = 1060`) but the really result is `1060.8`:

```
function sumResult() {
  var bookSumFT = parseInt(document.getElementById("bookSum").value);
  var bookRivFT = parseInt(document.getElementById("bookRiv").value)
  var bookIVTFT = parseInt(document.getElementById("bookIVT").value)
  var bookRitFT = parseInt(document.getElementById("bookRit").value)
  document.getElementById("bookAllCalc").value = bookSumFT + bookRivFT + bookIVTFT - bookRitFT;
}
```

How do I calculate the correct sum with decimal values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) will convert your values to integers. That is, without the decimal part.

Use [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) or [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)  instead of `parseInt()`

Comment: Thanks for your answare. Now I know this!